How can I fix the gap under one side of garage door? Garage/driveway height difference
The left side track is above the driveway (although technically still resting on the garage floor) and the right side sits on the garage. There's a step between the garage and driveway so it leaves a significant gap on the left side. I put a new garage door seal on but the height difference between the garage and driveway is too large.
Is there a quick fix that I could do today and then what's a long term solution? Thanks :)




Measure the diagonals of the door opening. If they are not equal, the opening is not a rectangle, and the building may need to be adjusted. But I guess the pictures mostly show that the garage floor is not well lined up with the garage itself.

There are extra thick garage door seals.  I would install one of those and check the down stop if there is an opener.  adjust to allow the door to close slightly more if possible.

I tried adjusting the closing distance but I had to turn up the closing force more than I'd like to compress the seal somewhat and there's still a gap. A larger seal could help though.

You need a bottom seal that can squish more on one side than the other.

Given that it appears the garage was built out of line with the floor, your apparent quick fix would be a bag or two of cold-patch asphalt to build up the floor under the whole door to the level of the floor on the right side, and your longer term fix would be to cut out a section of concrete a foot or so wide centered on the door so you can pour a new section of floor that is the same height as the garage floor under the whole door, and which then slopes down to the driveway level only after it's outside the garage door.
Adding a little bit of concrete on top to correct it is probably just going to spall off, but I suppose you could try that if you accept that it likely won't last. Using thinset mortar might improve your odds a bit for that approach.

Is there a method where the colors will be similar so it's not as visible as black asphalt on concrete? Would you do the asphalt for ease of closing the gap and add some concrete on top just for the color matching?

I've read (but not personally tried) that brushing (with a broom) cement powder on top of asphalt will make it much whiter. But if color match is your concern, try cleaning what's there really, really well and attempt the mortar/thinset method - worst that happens is it spalls off in the winter and you're back where you started.
